# Get string with number of specified length

Tags: php, regex

Supposing there's an array as the following:

```
$arr = array('foo1234bar', 'foo1234', '1234bar', 'foo12345bar');
```

and I just need the elements that contains **4** characters in total **only**. So except for *foo12345bar*, other 3 elements are valid.

Because `'\d{4}'` would match *foo12345bar*, so I try following clumsily:

```
$arr = array('foo1234bar', 'foo1234', '1234bar', 'foo12345bar');
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    preg_match('/\d+/', $value, $match);
    if (strlen($match[0]) != 4) {
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = $value;
}
var_dump($result);    //array('foo1234bar', 'foo1234', '1234bar')
```

Is there a regular expression to match directly(so the **if** condition can be omitted)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This easy to handle with look-around regex and [`preg_grep` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$arr = array('foo1234bar', 'foo1234', '1234bar', 'foo12345bar');
print_r(preg_grep('/(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)/', $arr));
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<!\d)  # assert previous char is not a digit
\d{4}    # match exact 4 digits
(?!\d)   # assert next char is not a digit
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo1234bar
    [1] => foo1234
    [2] => 1234bar
)
```

Comment: Best solution, as usual

Comment: Agreed ...! Best solution like always .. +1

Comment: Best solution...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your regex as follows

```
/^\D*\d{4}\D*$/
```

#### Explaination

`^` your string must start with
`\D` any non-digit char
`*` repeated from 0 to infinite times 
`\d{4}` followed by any digit repeated EXACTLY 4 times 
`\D` followed by any non-digit char
`*` repeated from 0 to infinite times 
`$` end of the string

Moreover you could modify your code as follows

```
$arr = array('foo1234bar', 'foo1234', '1234bar', 'foo12345bar');
$result = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function($element) {
        return preg_match('/^\D*\d{4}\D*$/', $element); 
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```

#### Pay attention

As OP didn't specify it, this regex will match even 1234 (any four digit string without non-digit chars in front or behind). If he wishes to have at least a char in front or/and behind, this regex must be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the characters in front of and after the numbers will always be alphabetical, you can use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]*\d{4}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: It won't catch "1234bar". First + should be changed to *.

Answer (score 0):

the regexp will be \d{4}

```
 preg_match('/\d{4}/', $value, $match);
```

expect will help

Answer (score 0):

you might try folowing :
   `preg_match('/\D\d{4}\D/', $value, $match);` 
 
it searches for: 
a not digit(/D) 
4 digits(/d{4}) 
again a non digit(/D)

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will work on all your examples:

```
'/^\D*(\d{4})\D*$/'
  ││   │     │  └── end string
  ││   │     └───── zero or more NOT digits
  ││   └─────────── four digits ( match 1 )
  │└─────────────── zero or more NOT digits
  └──────────────── start string
```

They doesn't work if there are multiple number group in the string ( '123abc1234o' ).